# An alias for git's --pretty option string format

Tags: git, format, git-log

I know I can set an alias for `git log` invocation with lots of parameters.

For example, I can use this:

`git config --global alias.lg "log --graph --pretty=format:'%h -%d %s (%cr) <%an>'"`

to alias `git log --graph --pretty=format:'%h -%d %s (%cr) <%an>'` with much shorter `git lg`.

Is it possible to set an alias for a `--pretty=format:` string alone? So that I can type

`git log --pretty=my_aliased_format`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) has this to say about the `--pretty[=<format>]` and `--format=<format>` options (the `--format` one has a required `<format>` name while `--pretty` has an optional one).  This text is buried fairly far in, under [the section **PRETTY FORMATS**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats):

> There are several built-in formats, and you can define additional
>   formats by setting a pretty.<name> config option to either another
>   format name, or a *format:* string, as described below (see [git-
>   config(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)). ...

Hence:

```
$ git config pretty.foo 'bar %H baz'              # you might want --global here
$ git log --format=foo | head -3
bar b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a baz
bar a562a119833b7202d5c9b9069d1abb40c1f9b59a baz
bar 7fa92ba40abbe4236226e7d91e664bbeab8c43f2 baz
```

Simply write your own format from the directives listed in that section, give it a name, and put that name into your configuration (local or global) and then `--format=<name>` will access it.

It's more typical and conventional to set `lg` as an alias, as in your earlier example, but this works well too.

Comment: Thanks! I did go through the `git log` documentation, but somehow missed the part on defining additional formats.