# How to override git log --format=oneline actual format?

Tags: git, git-log

I have hard issue to rule out (which I do not want to bother you). To rule that issue out, I have found that on my failing system the command

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
```

is equivalent to:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:%H%x20%s
```

This makes the long hash output. At the same time

```
$ git log --oneline
```

makes short hash output. Which is the desired output.

On the not failing system the --pretty=oneline format is equivalent to:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:%h%x20%s
```

This makes short hash output.

I have been looking how to override the oneline configuration in git and it seems that the oneline is hard coded, i.e. I can not change the format with:

```
$ git config --global pretty.oneline %h%x20%s
```

I can make different pretty format

```
$ git config --global pretty.myline %h%x20%s
```

and it will show nicely the short hash with

```
$ git log --pretty=myline
```

The trouble is that I want to rule out the issue dependence to exact log command hash printout length. I can not use different command like

```
$ git log --pretty=format:%h%x20%s
```

Is there a way to override the pretty formats like oneline?

Comment: There is no way but you can [store your own pretty format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54644017/7976758).

Comment: `--oneline` can override `--pretty=oneline`. So can another `--pretty`. If you have to use `git log --pretty=oneline` without any other options, there seems no solution.

Comment: I have found some options:
`git config --global log.abbrevCommit 1`
`git config --global core.abbrev 7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overall analysis is correct, I get what you'd want to achieve, but **built-in pretty formats are unfortunately fixed**.

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-prettyltnamegt) :

> Note that an alias with the same name as a built-in format will be silently ignored.

---

However, the difference between these two git environments might be leveled in some other way. Maybe consider getting both installations to the same git version?